# "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mariadb

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Fri Jan 22 17:34:03 2021
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`base_calendars_exceptions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`base_calendars_exceptions` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_base_calendar_exception` INT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(254) NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  `start_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `end_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `free_week_days` SMALLINT(1) NULL,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `ID_idx` (`id_base_calendar_exception` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `ID_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_base_calendar_exception`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`base_calendars_settings` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`base_calendars_generated`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`base_calendars_generated` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_based_calendar_generated` INT NULL,
  `c_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `star_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `end_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `working_day` SMALLINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `day` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `day_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `week` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `month` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `month_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `quarter` SMALLINT(1) NULL,
  `year` SMALLINT(4) NULL,
  `day_of_year` SMALLINT(3) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `working_day`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`base_calendars_settings`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`base_calendars_settings` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  `is_blocked` SMALLINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_default` SMALLINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `default_start_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `default_end_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `first_day` SMALLINT(1) NULL,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`resource_calendar_settings`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`resource_calendar_settings` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key',
  `user_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'ID of employee',
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL COMMENT 'employee name',
  `surname` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT 'employee surname',
  `type_of_leave` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT 'time off type: vacation, sick leave, absence, other',
  `start_time` DATETIME NULL COMMENT 'time off start date',
  `end_time` DATETIME NULL COMMENT 'time off end date',
  `comments` VARCHAR(256) NULL COMMENT 'comment about time off',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`shift_calendar`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`shift_calendar` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT NULL COMMENT 'od of employee',
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL COMMENT 'name of employee',
  `surname` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT 'surname of employee',
  `start_time` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL COMMENT 'employee start time',
  `end_time` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL COMMENT 'employe end time',
  `operator_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Id of operator who made changes',
  `working_date` DATETIME NULL COMMENT 'datetime when employee work',
  `working_hours` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL COMMENT 'working hours per day',
  `is_weekend` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `holiday_idx` (`is_weekend` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `holiday`
    FOREIGN KEY (`is_weekend`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`base_calendars_generated` (`working_day`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Want to run the following sql but i got error
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `mydb`.`shift_calendar` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
Dont understand where is problem column is_weekend and working_day have the same type smalint(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual here:

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
> foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
> referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
> columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
> index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
> exist. This index might be silently dropped later if you create
> another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
> index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

However, the manual (this same text stretches back to MySQL 5.6 and perhaps beyond) is wrong in your case: such an index is **not** created and you have to do it yourself or your table creation fails.

What you want to do is this - compare the fiddles [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=486bba52d04fbbc64d3b58235466e440) (success) with  the one [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a81879d986f3eca7656b6e1896756047) (failure):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `base_calendars_generated` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_based_calendar_generated` INT NULL,
  `c_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `star_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `end_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `working_day` SMALLINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `day` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `day_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `week` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `month` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `month_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `quarter` SMALLINT(1) NULL,
  `year` SMALLINT(4) NULL,
  `day_of_year` SMALLINT(3) NULL,
  -- KEY (`working_day`),
  CONSTRAINT `uq_wk` UNIQUE (`working_day`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `working_day`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The important bit is:

```
  -- KEY (`working_day`),                     -- << also works, but shouldn't
  CONSTRAINT `uq_wk` UNIQUE (`working_day`),  -- << Standard SQL
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `working_day`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Note that I have a `UNIQUE` named `CONSTRAINT` on `working_day` - this is what **should** be done and is part of the SQL Standard. From [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=486bba52d04fbbc64d3b58235466e440), MySQL (*quelle surprise!*) supports what it calls `"an extension" of the standard:

> NDB requires an explicit unique key (or primary key) on any column
> referenced as a foreign key. InnoDB does not, which is an extension of
> standard SQL.

I would advise you to avoid these party tricks (err... extensions) - there's a reason they're part of the standard - use a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY` - by definition non-duplicated and `NOT NULL`) `CONSTRAINT` for your `FOREIGN KEY`s and you won't go wrong!

As an aside declaring `INTEGER`s as `INT(x)` where x is another number serves virtually no purpose whatsoever, unless you have bizarre ZEROFILL requirements - see Bill Karwin's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135854/470530) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5634147/470530)) - Karwin used to be some sort of manager at MySQL + see his rep.!

Having `working_day` as `UNIQUE` might require you to rejig your schema - but I'd advise you to do so!

Finally, a piece of advice - do **not** use SQL keywords (i.e. `day`, `month`, & `year` - and for MySQL: `quarter`) as your field or table names - it's confusing, makes debugging tricky and is just not good practice - you wouldn't have a variable called `int` in `C`! Make liberal use of apostrophes and try snake_case - e.g. the_day, the_month or the_year...

Also, always use named `CONSTRAINT`s - it's much better than receiving a message that `"... failed. Constraint xyz_343535 has been violated"`

Comment: Thank you a lot, i am new to DB engeneering your advices is very helpfull

Comment: @woidwalker - great - then please mark it as helpful and/or correct so that others with the same problem can more easily find an answer! Best of luck for your future with db's!

Answer (score 1):

every referenced column needs to have an index

**Edit:**
To expand my answer:

Mysql shows some warnings, which you still should address, because intege3rs have a fixed size 1 - 8 bytes so a number behind is unnecessary and obsolete

> 0 row(s) affected, 3 warning(s): 1681 Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 1681 Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 1681 Integer display width is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

But the error is following

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'holiday' in the referenced table 'base_calendars_generated'

For that you need a an index for a foreign key that is mandatory. usually it is a primary key so you don't need aditional indexes. but in your case `working_day`is not indexes.
So chenge yout tbale

do following instead

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`base_calendars_generated` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_based_calendar_generated` INT NULL,
  `c_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `star_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `end_hour` DECIMAL(4,2) NULL,
  `working_day` SMALLINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `day` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `day_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `week` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `month` SMALLINT(2) NULL,
  `month_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `quarter` SMALLINT(1) NULL,
  `year` SMALLINT(4) NULL,
  `day_of_year` SMALLINT(3) NULL,
  KEY (`working_day`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `working_day`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Because `working_day` is referenced by `shift_calendar`

Comment: Doesn't [appear to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=682077d1295963be6695e6942bf51a5a)!

Comment: @Vérace you misded the part with the index

Comment: and i run this at home too asnd it is working the upvote from the other user was wromg

Comment: I'll give you a +1 - your answer works, but it shouldn't! :-)  See my answer!

Comment: I dont understand, but your answer is working... workbench diagram doesnt show me that i need to put this part  "KEY (`working_day`)"  mayby you can answer more expanded

Comment: mysql show with your original ciode some warnings because if the integer, and an error

Comment: @woidwalker i extended my answer for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You have smallint(2) in the shift_calendar definition, but smallint(1) in the base_calendar_generated table definition. I don't know mysql, but would having the visual format mismatch cause this issue?  Only thing I can see that is different.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! You are correct (from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)) - `Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of fixed precision types such as INTEGER and DECIMAL must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.` - but it doesn't solve the problem - see my fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=682077d1295963be6695e6942bf51a5a).